# Errors while Installing node_modules on Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, npm-install

I installed nvm and npm on Amazon linux 2 and I pulled my code from github.
When I want to install node_modules, I get this Error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ec2-user/RealeState/node_modules/iconv
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/RealeState/node_modules/iconv/build'
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/iconv/binding.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/RealeState/node_modules/iconv/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@12.18.3 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/RealeState/node_modules/iconv/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/ec2-user/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/ec2-user/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/ec2-user/.cache/node-gyp/12.18.3/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/ec2-user/RealeState/node_modules/iconv',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! make: cc: Command not found
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/iconv/binding.o] Error 127
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.14.232-177.418.amzn2.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/RealeState/node_modules/iconv
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/.npm/_logs/2021-07-22T15_09_51_360Z-debug.log
```

Even I tried to give privileges to user but again it didn't work. Even I can not install any node packages each time I get the same error. I tried to upgrade my node, npm, and nvm version but again I got the same error. I would appreciate if you help me with this problem